# Dynamic routing based on global variable

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I have two different projects in one angular workspace.I want to change route dynamically based on global variable in app.routing.ts

Here is my app routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const project1 = {
 path: '',
 loadchildren: '../module1#module1'
};

const project 2 = {
 path: '',
 loadchildren: '../module2#module2'
};
const selectedProject = window.id === 1 ? project1 : project2;

const routes: Routes = [selectedProject];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: true,
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

It always go with second project.

**Note:
I want to load it with empty path instead of separate path like project1, project2.**

Try with both absolute and relative path also but it not works

Comment: Is your window.id changing? Console that and see! Also hardcode  project1 and project2 separately and check if routing is working for both of them.

Comment: window.id will not change. how you referring hard coding

Comment: By hardcoding I mean, `const routes: Routes = [selectedProject];` try `const routes: Routes = [project1];` and similar for project2, to make sure if they are loading correctly. Also if you are using the javascript window object, it doesn't have an id property so it should evaluate to undefined hence condition is false and it routes to project2.

Answer (score 0):

Only way it to create to separate routes array and load them according project, but disadvantage of this is you should reload on every window.id change.

Lazy loading modules should be imported in `angular.json` with absolute path. e.x:

```
 "lazyModules": [
     "projects/website/src/app/pages/module1",
      "projects/website/src/app/pages/module2"
 ]
```

And in during you router configuration, should be pasted absolute path instead of relative:

```
    export const PROJECT1_ROUTES = [{
       path: '/1',
       loadchildren: 'projects/website/src/app/pages/module1#Module1'
    }]

    export const PROJECT2_ROUTES = [{
       path: '*',
       loadchildren: 'projects/website/src/app/pages/module2#Module2'
    }]

    var routes = [];
    @NgModule({
       imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
       exports: [RouterModule]
    })

    export class AppRoutingModule {
        constructor(
            private router: Router
        ) {
            const selectedProject = window.id === 1 ? true : false;
            if(selectedProject) {
                this.router.resetConfig(PROJECT1_ROUTES)
            } else {
                this.router.resetConfig(PROJECT2_ROUTES)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it not working, thown error like core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "./module/module1.module.ngfactory".
Error: Cannot find module "./module/module1.module..ngfactory".

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change routes using a global variable, for many reasons.

- Routing uses browser's URL.
- Variable scoping, global variables are not looked for change.
- You're assigning "selectedProject" on loading, and this is evaluated on laod and defines your route object.

In order to use route to select between modules use a param key, or assign a route:

```
const project1 = {
 path: '/1',
 loadchildren: '../module1#module1'
};

const project 2 = {
 path: '*',
 loadchildren: '../module2#module2'
};
```

Of course, you'll have to make use of [route & navigation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-a-navigation-link-routerlink)